# Why is "I too" so rare?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrase-usage, expression-choice

It would be interesting to hear the reasons why "I too" is so rare. It is usually replaced by "me too", although this is techically wrong when it denotes the subject. Perhaps it is because "I too" sounds too similar to "I do"?

Comment: Instead of using "I too did it" we usually say "I did it too".

Comment: While it is true that this question is a duplicate, it should be noted that none of the answers to the question that it is a duplicate of really explains 'why "I too" is so rare' and 'usually replaced by "me too", although this is technically wrong when it denotes the subject'. The posted answers essentially just confirm that it is rare, and offer practical advice on how to avoid the problem altogether. The question thus still needs an answer.

Comment: _I_ can only occur as the subject of a sentence, where it's usually contracted. _Too_ is far more common at the end of sentences than the beginning, and is much less frequent than _also_ after _I_. The reason is because (a) _I, too,_ raises a comma problem; (b) one syllable between a single vowel and its following verb -- normally an auxiliary -- is basically a timing stumble; you want to get to the verb as fast as possible, but the _too_ gets in the way with a parenthetic observation. If it's important enough to interrupt, it should be at least two syllables. There's also (c) and (d), I think